# How do I merge string with a Row to create a new spark dataframe when Row schema is unknown while coding?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, schema

I have created a function that takes a row as an input and gives a string as an output. I plan to apply this function to various dataframes whose schema would be different from each other. These dataframes are huge with millions of rows each but each dataframe has a defined schema

I want to create another function which will call the first function, merge the output string from the function with the row it sent to the function and create a new dataframe which will be the output of second function.

Both functions will be written in spark-scala environment. I am very new to spark-scala and not really sure how I can combine the rows into a new dataframe

```scala
def returnTranformFunctionOutput(inputDataRow: Row, TransformFrame: Array[Row]): String = {
 val resultString = "testdata"
    resultString
  }

  def returnOutputDataframe(inputDataframe: DataFrame, TranformFrame: Array[Row]): DataFrame = {

    val inputSchema = inputDataframe.schema
    val outputSchema =  StructType(StructField("outputVal", StringType, true) :: Nil)
    val final_schema = StructType((inputSchema ++ outputSchema))
    val newDf = inputDataframe.map(row => {
      return Row.merge(row,TransformFunctions.returnTranformFunctionOutput(row,TranformFrame))
    }),final_schema)
    newDf
  }
```

the `returnOutputDataframe` doesnt compile and gives me multiple errors including `no implicits found for parameter evidence$6: Encoder[U_]` and `type mismatch: Required:Row Found:string` when doing the Row.merge.

Can a string and a row be merged to create a new row which can then be combined into a new dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to return `Dataframe` in `returnOutputDataframe` but .map step will produce `Dataset` and you are passing schema instead of encoder too. You could transform `inputDataframe` to `RDD[Row]`, map values and then create DF using spark.createDataFrame with new schema. see example below.

```
  val row1 = RowFactory.create("1","2")
  val schema1 = new StructType()
    .add("c0","string")
    .add("c1","string")

  val row2 = RowFactory.create("A","B")
  val schema2 = new StructType()
    .add("c2","string")
    .add("c3","string")


  val df1 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Seq(row1)),schema1)
  df1.show()

  val rdd = df1.rdd.map(s => Row.merge(s, row2))
  val schema = StructType(schema1 ++ schema2)

  val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
  df.printSchema()
  df.show()
```

```
    +---+---+
    | c0| c1|
    +---+---+
    |  1|  2|
    +---+---+

    root
     |-- c0: string (nullable = true)
     |-- c1: string (nullable = true)
     |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
     |-- c3: string (nullable = true)

    +---+---+---+---+
    | c0| c1| c2| c3|
    +---+---+---+---+
    |  1|  2|  A|  B|
    +---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks. This was very useful. I did change it a little bit by using a `RowEncoder` and avoiding `df1.rdd.map` in favour of `df1.map`. Is there any advantage of using df1.rdd.map over df1.map?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from chlebek above, my final function was:

```
def returnOutputDataframe( inputDataframe: DataFrame, TranformFrame: Broadcast[Array[Row]]): DataFrame = {
val inputSchema = inputDataframe.schema
val outputSchema =  StructType(StructField("outputval", StringType, true) :: Nil)
val final_schema = StructType((inputSchema ++ outputSchema))
val schemaEncoder = RowEncoder(final_schema)
val outputDf = inputDataframe.map(row =>
  Row.merge(row,RowFactory.create(returnTranformFunctionOutputString(row, TranformFrame))))(schemaEncoder)
outputDf
   }
}
```

In my tests, using `inputDataframe.map` seemed faster than `inputDataframe.rdd.map` and it avoided having to use the `createDataFrame` step.